# Django admin different list_display based on what filter is selected?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I want to display based on a Boolean field filter different list_displays for my model in Django admin. For example, if the boolean field is **false** I should **list_display=('name', 'age')** but if is **true** I should display **list_display=('name', 'school', 'grades')** assuming that my Model have all those fields.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documents](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_display) best practice would be using `ModelAdmin.get_list_display` which allow you to change `list_display` per request

```
class MySimpleListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
      parameter_name = 'filter_parameter_name'
      ...

class MyModelAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
      list_display = ('my','default','fields')

      def get_list_display(self,request):
          if request.GET.get('filter_parameter_name',None) is not None:
             return self.list_display + ['my_protected_column']

      def my_protected_column(self,instance):
          return "Protected column for "+str(instance)
```